# Using links to Code/Error Code

Tags: discussion, specific-question, external-links

Today I saw a question which only contained two links, one to a screenshot of the sourcecode and one to a screenshot of the error the user get when hes running the code.

Just like this:

> [When ever iam adding middleware to kernel i am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq6he.png)
>
> [This is my middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioIzK.png)

I don't think that a question like this should be used because links won't last forever. And it could be that someone else with the same problem won't get help from this question if the links died. But I haven't found any rules/guidelines about link only question.

Are there any rules to links to external code/screenshots and whats your personal opinion to such questions?

Comment: If you take into account that some companies block image providers, the question becomes blank so the problem isn't even about links dying, its that they are completely inaccessible to some users in the first place.

Comment: True, never though about this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is a rule: this is unacceptable for the reasons you mentioned.

Such questions should be flagged: flag → "should be closed" → "off topic because…" → "**Questions seeking debugging help** ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Code *absolutely* must be posted as text, not as an image.